# How to render json with extra data with active_model_serializer on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, active-model-serializers

Using Rails 4.1.6 and active_model_serializers 0.10.3

app/serializers/product_serializer.rb

```
class ProductSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :price, :published
  has_one :user
end
```

app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb

```
class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    products = Product.search(params).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
    render json: products, meta: pagination(products, params[:per_page])
  end
end
```

When I check the response body, it shows the products data only:

```
[{:id=>1, :title=>"Side Auto Viewer", :price=>"1.6999510872877", :published=>false, :user=>{:id=>2, :email=>"indira.sawayn@watsica.us", :created_at=>"2016-12-29T03:44:40.450Z", :updated_at=>"2016-12-29T03
:44:40.450Z", :auth_token=>"ht7CsFWM1hvSGKM_zPmU"}}, {:id=>2, :title=>"Direct Gel Mount", :price=>"56.7935950121941", :published=>false, :user=>{:id=>3, :email=>"jaye.rolfson@leuschke.info", :created_at=>
"2016-12-29T03:44:40.467Z", :updated_at=>"2016-12-29T03:44:40.467Z", :auth_token=>"MTK_5rkFv8E6Fy7gyAtM"}}, {:id=>3, :title=>"Electric Tag Kit", :price=>"46.4689779902597", :published=>false, :user=>{:id=
>4, :email=>"tatiana@moen.co.uk", :created_at=>"2016-12-29T03:44:40.479Z", :updated_at=>"2016-12-29T03:44:40.479Z", :auth_token=>"fTd8z7PCLHxZ7aewLPDY"}}, {:id=>4, :title=>"Remote Tuner", :price=>"48.2478
906626996", :published=>false, :user=>{:id=>5, :email=>"pauline.gaylord@hettinger.info", :created_at=>"2016-12-29T03:44:40.486Z", :updated_at=>"2016-12-29T03:44:40.486Z", :auth_token=>"XC7ZhcyfPrpEyDw-M15
1"}}]
```

The extra data `meta` was not been picked up. Is this `active_model_serializers` version not support that? Or is there a way can get extra data?

---

## Edit

The `pagination` method:

```
def pagination(paginated_array, per_page)
  { pagination: { per_page: per_page.to_i,
                  total_pages: paginated_array.total_pages,
                  total_objects: paginated_array.total_count } }
end
```

Comment: try smth like this, personally havn't tested it. `render json: products.merge(meta: pagination(products, params[:per_page]))` and check serializer

Comment: Where is the `pagination` method?

Comment: @7urkm3n I have tried that. But the same result.

Comment: @31piy `pagination` is a method outside this controller. Just think that's a value here.

Comment: @JingqiangZhang I am not well versed with `meta`, but as per the [docs here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/fca2d4515dbb6ae73272a69485a1fbc2726aee97/docs/general/rendering.md#meta), the meta should be passed as a hash. Does `pagination` method do that?

Comment: @31piy I have edited the topic and added the `pagination` method. Yes, as the documentation, it looks good about that usage. So maybe the version trouble.

Comment: @JingqiangZhang -- umm, not sure, but can you try removing the root key `pagination` from the response of `pagination` method?

Comment: @31piy Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same issue, and it's been fixed by specifying the adapter to use in the call to render method:

```
app/controllers/api/v1/products_controller.rb

class Api::V1::ProductsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    products = Product.search(params).page(params[:page]).per(params[:per_page])
    render json: products, meta: pagination(products, params[:per_page]), adapter: :json
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Pierre. Worked for me. Note that you need to call your second key `meta` and not any other name for this to work